# position absolute, limit its size

Tags: css

i have always wondered how to limit the area a element with position absolute covers.

Ex: i have a container div, lets say its 100 x 100

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="overlap"></a>
<div class="content">some content...</div>
</div>
```

i want the anchor to overlap all content in the container div.
i style the anchor with

```
z-index:10;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

but it seems to overlap the whole site, which is unwanted :)
how do i do this ?

Comment: Your code is a bit broken ;) you're closing container with a open anchor tag in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility (of many):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="overlap"></a>
<div class="content">some content...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.overlap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/93VPp/

Additional example, based on code provided by the original poster: http://jsfiddle.net/aqyFP/3/

Comment: You bet me to it :( i made a fiddle as well. P.s. you don't have to specify the properties of left/top etc. http://jsfiddle.net/D2kbA/

Comment: @Bankzilla I specified them as an alternative to height/width of 100%, though you could definitely do things in a variety of ways.

Comment: well that was the code i figured my self, but it doesnt work... 
http://jsfiddle.net/aqyFP/1/

Comment: @Flaashing Here is what I think you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/aqyFP/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can give the anchor's parent element a position of "relative":

```
.container { position:relative }
```

Comment: for some strange reason it doesnt work, it just disables all the css code

Comment: @Flaashing Can you post more of your code, then? Perhaps a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), something we can mess around with?

Answer (score 0):

100% means 100% of its **container**. When something is positioned absolutely it is taken out of the document flow and the only container is the `<body>`. So it will expand to the size `<body>`.

You need to define dimensions in pixels, not percent.

Comment: This is not really true if the containing element is `position:relative`.